# CSS fluid 'column'

Tags: css, layout

Whats the best way to get this layout in CSS? imagine that I have three divs, two divs inside another.. of the two inner divs, the first one has a specific width set, and the second div is expected to take up the remaining space.

Generally I'd end up setting a specific width on the second column, and manage updating this in the end that the containing div width changed.

If I float the fixed but not the fluid, the fluid column will wrap underneath the fixed div (not what is wanted).

```
+-------+  +--------------------------------------+
| fixed |  |                                      |
+-------+  |               fluid                  |
           |                                      |        
           |                                      |
           +--------------------------------------+

<div>
  <div>fixed</div>
  <div>fluid</div>
</div>
```

This has to be an entirely css solution, no javascript frameworks- and ideally works on most commonly used browsers with minimum 'hackage' (if at all).

Hope the ASCII art works,

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the markup

```
<div id="fixed">fixed content</div>
<div id="fluid">fluid content</div>
```

the css

```
#fixed {
  float: left;
  width: 13em;
  margin-right: -14em;
}
#fluid {
  margin-left: 14em;
}
```

That should do the trick. I use it on my personal site. The margins make it all stay on the same level.

Comment: This is one of the core techniques of the so-called "Holy Grail" layout and has proven to be robustly cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Emastic CSS Framework](http://code.google.com/p/emastic/) that support fluid columns. Here [Link](http://www.allapis.com/Emastic-CSS-Temaplates/template9.html) is working example similar to your "ASCII art work" :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this at least helps you get started:

```
* {
   margin:0;
}

div#wrapper {
   margin:0;
   height:auto !important; //IE Hack
   height:100%; //IE Hack
   min-height:100%;
   overflow:auto
}

div#fixed{
   float:left;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:red;
   margin:0;
   height:200px;
   width:200px
}

div#fluid{
   float:right;
   position:absolute;
   left:200px;
   background-color:blue;
   display:block;
   height:80%;
   width:60%
}
```

The "wrapper" would be your wrapping div.  I only set the fluid column to a width of 60% so you could see that it should act fluidly.  I tested this in Opera 10, IE 6, and Firefox 3 with only minor problems.  IE wants to append an extra 200px to the right if you set the width of the fluid column to 100%.  I'm sure there is a work around for this somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an even easier solution to this which i discovered not too long ago. Works well back to IE7. The #fluid div will slide up next to the fixed fix and take up the remaining space while maintaining great fluidity for all responsive sites.

```
#fixed{
     width:200px;
     float:left;
}
#fluid{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```